# Fetching data from a dataframe in python

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

I have 3000 raw data with time and the amount of consumed energy. But this energy value is cumulative sum and I need to get the monthly consumption value for each month.
I want to know how can I loop through the data from the same month and subtract the last value of each month from the first value of the same month.
The number of data I have from each month is different from the other months. The first values of this list is as below:

```
Time             Energy

2017-01-01                0.0
2017-01-01      456682295.279
2017-01-01      576253341.508
2017-01-01      693234839.384
2017-01-02      810613281.137
2017-01-02      928960004.805
.
.
.
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to compare last day of each month? Seems like if you compare last day with first day, you'll miss one day

Comment: So maybe subtracting the first day of each month from the first day of last month would work better?

Comment: Yep, that would work

Comment: But the question is how can I loop through the months? I am a beginner in python

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in the form of a dataframe. Then the data can be grouped by Time variable.

consider your data is in variable **df**. Convert your Time variable to string and take only 7 character of it so that it will represent only month

```
df=df.drop(df.index[0]) 
df.columns= ["Time","Energy"] 
df['Time']= df["Time"].map(lambda x: x[:7])  # Should be of form yyyy-mm


def diff(x):
    return max(x) - min(x)

df.groupby(["Time"]).agg(diff)
```

Comment: yes,they are in dataframe. Thank you for your super fast reply. The script I have so far is: df=df.drop(df.index[0])
df.columns= ["Time","Energy"]
df['Time']= pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.date
def diff(x):
    return max(x) - min(x)
df.groupby(["Time"]).agg(diff), but I recieved an error of:unsupported operand type, as I added what you told me.

Comment: Is your time variable a string or a datetime object?

Comment: It is a string.

Comment: According to your comment you were converting it to datetime. I have updated the code.

Comment: I still get the same error: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str

Answer (score 0):

You can group by month and use `pd.TimeGrouper`. Here is a trivial example.

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-02',
                            '2017-02-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-02-02', '2017-02-02',
                            '2017-03-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-03-02', '2017-03-02'],
                   'Energy': list(range(12))})

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

**Solution**

```
res = df.set_index('Time').sort_index()
res = res.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).nth(0).reset_index()   
res['Monthly'] = res['Energy'].diff().fillna(0)
```

**Result**

```
        Time  Energy  Monthly
0 2017-01-31       0      0.0
1 2017-02-28       4      4.0
2 2017-03-31       8      4.0
```

Comment: I tried your method but I recieve this error: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'. Also thanks a lot for quick reply.

Comment: This works with the data I provided, the structure of which I got from your question. Either you haven't implemented the logic as in my post, or your data is different. Happy to help if you figure out which.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
import itertools


for item, group in itertools.groupby(data, lambda x: x["Time"][:7]):
    total = sum([each_item["Energy"] for each_item in group]) # Here you sum
```

UPD: group in loop for you can iterate only once.